# Inheriting overloaded functions: Requires namespace?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

If I have an overloaded function in a base class, why do I need to declare the namespace of the base class for all overloaded copies that I do not re-implement (given I've re-implemented at least one).  Consider the following code for example:

```
#include <iostream>


class Base {
protected:
    int bar;

public:
    Base() : bar(0) {}
    virtual void Bar(int b) { bar = b; }
    virtual int Bar() { return bar; }
};

class Foo : public Base {
protected:
    int extraBar;

public:
    //virtual void Bar(int b) { extraBar = b; }  //Uncomment
};

int main() {

    Foo T;

    std::cout << T.Base::Bar() << std::endl;
    std::cout << T.Bar() << std::endl; //will cause code to not compile

    return 0;
}
```

Is there an easy way around it?  I would have to modify several lines of code by hand since I have

```
 func()
 func(var)
 func(var, var, var)
```

and var is never the same thing so find and replace on func(var) won't work so well.

Comment: @Adam What in heavens are you talking about?

Comment: C++ programs are not scripts.

Comment: Eh, I script some I code some, It's late.

Comment: No worries. BTW, I believe your predicament is because T is a `Foo` and not a `Foo*`. Virtual-ness is done through pointers. Otherwise  I believe it tries to call Foo::Bar, which doesn't exist, though I could be wrong on this detail.

Comment: @Adam No, it is not to do with using pointers. It is name hiding.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, you're right. I missed the `uncomment this` comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
using Base::Bar;
```

in `Foo` class. Compiler will not find `Bar` without arguments, without `using`, since it's hidden by `Foo::Bar` function.

> A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region or derived
> class

Comment: `using Base::Bar;` fixed it.  I find it curious that `using Base::Bar;` wasn't needed if no overloads were reimplemented. which makes me think I don't understand overloaded operators very much.  `Bar()` and `Bar(var)`, in my mind, were two different functions so when it doesn't find `Foo::Bar()` I thought it should default like normal to the `Base::Bar()`.  Thanks!